# Ajax and readyState

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to update my ajax request function to show the individual states of the response.

However all I get after I send the request is `readyState = 1` and then it jumps directly to  `readyState = 4` and I get the full response from the server.

Why am I not getting readyStates 2 and 3?

When I experimented with native browser, e.g.

```
xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest()
```

Sending the same requests gets me readyStates 1, 2, 3, and 4 in my callback:

```
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange
```

But with the JQuery ajax helper function does not. Why is this occuring?

Here is my code:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax(
{
    data: requestForm, //my json request
    type: req_type, // could be post or get
    url: script, // php script
    async: true,
    success: function(response,textStatus, xhr) 
    {
          renderIt(response);
    },

    error: function( xhr, textStatus, errorThrown )
    {
        var errText = "<b>Error "+xhr.status+" : "+xhr.reponseText+" , "+textStatus+", "+errorThrown+" </b>";
        $('#'+div).append(errText);
    }
});

jqXHR.fail(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) 
{
   var errText = "<b>Error "+jqXHR.status+" : "+jqXHR.reponseText+" , "+textStatus+", "+" </b>";
   $('#'+div).html(errText);
});

switch(jqXHR.readyState) 
{
case 1:
    $('#'+div).html("\n<center> Connected to Server...<br/> <img src='images/loading.gif' height=30 width=30></center>\n");
    break;
case 2:
    $('#'+div).html("\n<center> Request Recieved...<br/> <img src='images/loading.gif' height=30 width=30></center>\n");
    break;
case 3:
    $('#'+div).html("\n<center>  Receiving Responses.....<br/> <img src='images/loading.gif' height=30 width=30></center>\n");
    $('#'+div).append(xhr.responseText);
    break;
default:
    $('#'+div).html("\n<center>  Awaiting Results.."+jqXHR.readyState+"<br/> <img src='images/loading.gif' height=30 width=30></center>\n");
    break;                                    
 }
```

Comment: You realize that switch statement only executes once, right?

Comment: You are right! How do I bind the switch code to be triggered by a readyState change?

Comment: use the readystatechange event? Note however that requires not using jQuery's ajax methods.

Comment: There are ways of doing it using jQuery, but it's a hack at best. you would need to supply a callback to the xhr option that returns an xhr, then bind to the onreadystatechange event on that xhr before you returned it.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought that .onreadystatechange() is not available for jqXHR object based on this doc http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Something would have to be pretty slow to even see the different stages between 1 and 4. I'd be willing to bet that 99% of the time, you'll see "Connected" flash on screen for a millisecond, then the final results screen.

Comment: It isn't, but it IS available on the xhr that you would return to the xhr parameter.

Comment: Like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/4L3kM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only get 1 and 4 in jQuery because its success callback only fires once the ajax request completes, and [it does not expose a callback for the readystatechange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091587/state-of-xmlhttprequest-object-in-jquery-ajax).

So, if for some reason you need to be able to do some processing on this event, you will need to use XMLHttpRequest directly.

Comment: Based on this answer I guess I have to abandon my effort to make this change.  I started making it because some of the requests receive several chunks of data before the processing is complete and I wanted to show status to the waiting user.