# How to receive jQuery post response before completing execution of PHP script?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a simple jquery function that sends a post request to a PHP file like this:

```
$.post('/file.php',
{
     action: 'send'   
},

function(data, textStatus)
{     
     alert(data);
});
```

And a PHP file:

```
<?php

/* Some SQL queries here */

echo 'action done';

/* echo response back to jquery and continue other actions here */

?>
```

jQuery by default waits till executing the whole PHP script before giving the alert. Is there a way to alert the *action done* before executing the rest of the PHP file??

Thanks

Comment: The "action done" message is sent by PHP. There is not way to get the response _before_ the script terminates.

Comment: @SalmanA that's only true if output buffering is on, otherwise `action done` will be sent to the browser before the execution completes.

Comment: Yes, the "action done" message could be sent to the browser before the script terminates but the success/complete events of AJAX handler will not be fires until the connection is closed.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with plain Javascript ajax. The `onreadystatechange` event will fire with a `readyState` of 3, when data is received before the request is complete.

In the example below, `newData` will contain the new piece of data. We have to do some processing because the XHR actually gives us the entire data so far in `responseText` and so if we only want to know the new data, we have to keep a record of the last index.

```
var httpRequest, lastIndex = 0;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 8 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(httpRequest.readyState === 3) {
        var newData = httpRequest.responseText.substring(lastIndex);
        lastIndex = httpRequest.responseText.length;

        console.log(newData);
    } 
};

httpRequest.open('POST', '/file.php');
httpRequest.send('action=send');
```

As for jQuery ajax, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309185/jquery-ajax-overwrite-onreadystatechange-handler#5048527) suggests jQuery lets you bind to the `readystatechange` but I haven't tested it.