# readyState event for HEADERS_RECEIVED using jQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, readystate

Using the native `XMLHttpRequest` object, it's possible to add an event listener to the `onreadystatechange` event, and be notified when the [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#readyState) is `2`, or `HEADERS_RECEIVED`.
This is useful, as this enables the reading of the HTTP response headers before a long transfer is completed.

However in jQuery's AJAX wrapper, there doesn't seem to be any way to do this. The [jQuery.ajax API documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) actually says the following.

> No `onreadystatechange` mechanism is provided, however, since `done`, `fail`, `always`, and `statusCode` cover all conceivable requirements.

Unless I'm mistaken, all of the listed callbacks are fired after the entire request is received, which may be a long time after the headers are available and `readyState` is `2`.

Is there a way to add a callback to `onreadystatechange` and/or `readyState` `2` when using jQuery's AJAX wrapper, without polling the `readyState` property?

I suppose it would be possible to poll the `readyState` property of the AJAX object using `setInterval`, but I do not consider this to be a real solution for obvious reasons. I also do not consider modifying jQuery's core to be a real solution either.

**Update:**

Another SO user directed me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309185/jquery-ajax-overwrite-onreadystatechange-handler). Unfortunately, none of those answers seem to work. Modifying jQuery is not a real solution. Using jQuery to create a XHR object kind-of defeats the purpose. And the last answer doesn't work at all. In fact, the whole question looks to be for an outdated jQuery.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309185/jquery-ajax-overwrite-onreadystatechange-handler) question.

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately, none of those answers seem to work. Modifying jQuery is not a real solution. Using jQuery to create a XHR object kind-of defeats the purpose. And the last answer doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the short answer is that jQuery does not provide this functionality due to compatibility issues in legacy browsers. To resolve the issues, jQuery simply lowers the bar to the lowest common denominator.

The slightly longer answer is it can be monkey patched into it, using the `beforeSend` and `xhr` methods, but this is not trivial, especially when you factor in legacy and cross-browser compatibility. To ease the pain, [I've create a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/AlexanderOMara/jquery-ajaxreadystate) that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible. Get the `XMLHttpRequest` object from jQuery then monitor for state changes as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange

Example code from the documentation:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  // In local files, status is 0 upon success in Mozilla Firefox
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status === 0 || (status >= 200 && status < 400)) {
      // The request has been completed successfully
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      // Oh no! There has been an error with the request!
    }
  }
};
```